# Problems with BufferedWriter and Calendar.getTime(): If BufferedWriter has to wait, the Calendar object becomes stuck

Tags: java, date, calendar, bufferedwriter

I'm using a simple method to write a String to a file in my application like this:

```
dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd MMMM YYYY HH:mm:ss");
cal = Calendar.getInstance();

public boolean writeToFile(String daten) {
    try {
        in = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(
            new FileOutputStream(myFile, true), "UTF-8"));
        in.write(dateformat.format(cal.getTime());
        in.write(daten);
        in.newLine();
        in.close();
    }
}
```

This works fine, but there are up to three clients using this method to write to the same file. The good thing is: The BufferedWriter waits till he can open the file if another client is writing and writes then the line.

But now there occurs a problem where the timestaps on some computer will be the same till you reopen the application. So the `dateformat.format(cal.getTime());` seems not to return the actual date but a much oder time.

I guess that the problem occurs if the file isn't accessible for a moment and the `BufferedReader` waits. Because of that the `dateformat.format(cal.getTime())` becomes stuck.

Is this a known problem and does anyone has an idea how to fix that? Thank you!

Comment: I believe dateformat.format is not thread safe.

Comment: @Davio Correct, the docs say so.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A `Calendar` is basically a `Date` that also knows how to divide the milliseconds since epoch it stores into arbitrary sub-divisions like days, weeks, months, etc. `cal.getTime()` just returns the milliseconds since epoch as a `Date`.

This means that the value `cal.getTime()` returns is fixed from the moment you first call `Calendar.getInstance()`. It will never return the current time. This isn't anything about the writer (the writer has absolutely nothing to do with anything). It's just how the function works.

You should just use `new Date()` at the point where you want a `Date` representing the current time. Leave `Calendar` out of it.

As @Dario pointed out in his comment, `DateFormat.format` is not thread-safe! Each thread should have its own instance.

And finally, don't use `YYYY`, use `yyyy`! Upper-case Y is the week-year, i.e. the year into which the majority of the calendar week of the specified `Date` falls in. This means that it returned 2015 for 29 December 2014 (if you're in a culture where the week starts on Monday, not Sunday), because that week had three days in 2014 and four in 2015. A friend of mine had her company's enterprise application grind to a halt because of this bug!

Comment: Thanks for you answer that was very helpful! I use this method since 2 months and it worked fine. Now I implemented it to another application and the problem occurs. I found out that my first application created a new object of the class where this method is before the method was called, so the `cal.getTime()` was always the current time or very close to it. So a `cal = Calendar.getInstance()` before `dateFormat.format(cal.getTime())` should do it.

Comment: @parboiledRice You're welcome. I've updated the answer with some other important information.

Comment: Thanks for this very informative answer. I took my method from a tutorial but changed it now to the suggested form like you and Bruno Marco Visioli suggest.

Answer (score 1):

The time returned is the one of the instance creation at `Calendar.getInstance()`. Maybe you should instantiate it at the time of recording so you don't see this gap. Try this: `dateformat.format(new Date())`.

Comment: Thank you very much! I've changed it to your suggested form. I've used the `Calendar` because a tutorial told me, but your way is much easier and works! Thanks!